# Stream audio and video data in network in html5

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, html5-video

How do I achieve streaming of audio and video data and pass it on the network. I gone through a good article [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-simple), But did not get in depth. I want to have chat application in `HTML5`

There are mainly below question

1. How to stream the audio and video data
2. How to pass to particular IP address.
3. Get that data and pass to video and audio control

Comment: are you looking to stream live content, or stored media files?

Comment: I am mainly looking for live content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve a stream, you need a server doing so, by either downloading and installing, or coding on your own.

Streams only work in one direction, there is no responding or "retrieve back". Streaming is almost the same as downloading, with slight differences, depending on the service and use case.

Most streams are `downstreams`, but there are also `upstreams`. Did you hear about BufferStreams in PHP, Java, whatever? It's basically the same: `data` -> `direction` -> `cursor`.
Streams work over many protocols, even via different network layers, for example:

- network/subnet broadcast, peer 2 peer, HTTP, DLNA, even FTP streams, ...

The basic nature of a stream is nothing more than data beeing sent to an audience.

You need to decide:

- which protocol do you want to use for streaming
- which server software
- which media / source / live or with selectable start/end
- which clients

The most popular HTTP streaming server is Shoutcast by Nullsoft (Winamp).

There is also DLNA which afaik is not HTTP based.

To provide more information, you need to be more specific regarding your basic requirements and decisions.

Comment: Thanks for response.
1.Want to use Http protocol.
2.Do not want to use any third party software.
3.I want to stream audio and vedio data.
4.Client is web application only.

Comment: So you want something like justin.tv?